# Animation issue of Button in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation

i have a three buttons in home view controller . When i click but1 it perform animation and move toward right with a duration to a specific width. When but1 reach to its given width it hides and shows but2 there. when i hit but2 it perform animation and move back to the same position of but1. Its like a scenario of open and close of button. The issue now i'm facing is that when i open but1 it moves its given width and when i close it move back to original but1 position , now buttons open and close but when we try to open again it does not open with but1. I want that whenever user click but1 it should moves towards right with animation and every time user want to close the button it should close it rather than open or close only one time. My code for opening of button is this,

```
- (IBAction)openHome:(id)sender {

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(108, 0);
[_openHome setTransform:transform];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.75
                                  target:self
                               selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
```

}

```
-(void)targetMethod:(NSTimer *)myTimer{
_home.hidden=NO;
_openHome.hidden=YES;
_closeHome.hidden=NO;

[myTimer invalidate];
```

}

For closing the button its this,

```
- (IBAction)closeHome:(id)sender {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-110, 0);
[_closeHome setTransform:transform];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.75
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(targetMethoded:)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:NO];
```

}

```
-(void)targetMethoded:(NSTimer *)myTimer{
_home.hidden=YES;
_openHome.hidden=YES;
_closeHome.hidden=NO;

[myTimer invalidate];
```

}

The screen before open of button is this,
[image]

The screen after open of button,
[image]

Comment: Do you need the full rectangle (with the label and icon) to be the UIButton when it is "Open"? Or is just the icon (the House image) the button portion?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using CGAffineTransform to change the position just change the buttons frame directly. Also use the following code which uses the completion handler to call the targetMethod instead of using the NSTimer:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.75 animations:^{
    _openHome.frame = CGRectMake(_openHome.frame.origin.x+110, _openHome.frame.origin.y, _openHome.frame.size.width, _openHome.frame.size.height);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self targetMethod];
}];
```